# Removing the blank positions (x,y) from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text

I'm working on object tracking from video files, I have 5 to 6 objects in each frame of the video. Due to some bugs in the code there are some frames that are skipped and show as blank spaces in the text file . Like below

```
5.0  2.3 5.4 5.2 5.5 nan nan 9.4 9.9 nan nan 
5.06 
5.13 2.8 5.6 6.2 6.6 9.45 8.7 6.2 7.8 9.9 5.7
```

As you can see here, the second frame `5.06` has a blank row, wherein I want `nan`.

I have 60K frames per videos, Will you Please provide  some advice on how to change empty space to `nan` . It is really tedious to change manually for 60K frames. Thanks in advance . 
The expected output is

```
5.0  2.3 5.4 5.2 5.5 nan nan 9.4 9.9 nan nan
5.06 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
5.13 2.8 5.6 6.2 6.6 9.45 8.7 6.2 7.8 9.9 5.7
```

Comment: Your example already has nan, can you update the text file that has issue, and also if possible details on how many space those frames are

Comment: The first column is frame number .  The remaining are (x,y) positions . In each frame either i may have 3 to 6 objects . So If code doesn't find the more than three objects, it return "nan' to the remaining places. But here the frames are skipped for some reason, Now I want them manually to change it nan . Out of 60K frames I have 30 to 40 places the frames got skipped .

Comment: Can you please update your question with an example input and its expected output?

Comment: output Which I got is mentioned above ! please look at the update

Comment: Last question, how many nans should it replace with?

Comment: The maximum number of Objects is 6 . So 6 (nan,nan). But I mentioned only 5 in example .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a simple text file and each `frame` is in a new line. You can simply create a new file with the frames where there is only 1 element in the line and add 12 `nan` to those lines. Example code -

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f , open('newoutput.txt','w') as oF:
    for line in f:
        eles = line.split() # this splits the line by whitespaces
        if len(eles) == 1:
            line = eles[0] + " nan" * 12 + "\n"
        oF.write(line)
```

I gave the above program the following input  -

```
5.0  2.3 5.4 5.2 5.5 nan nan 9.4 9.9 nan nan 
5.06 
5.13 2.8 5.6 6.2 6.6 9.45 8.7 6.2 7.8 9.9 5.7
```

And it gave me the output -

```
5.0  2.3 5.4 5.2 5.5 nan nan 9.4 9.9 nan nan 
5.06 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
5.13 2.8 5.6 6.2 6.6 9.45 8.7 6.2 7.8 9.9 5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fillNans(fileName, itemsCount=10):
    fill = ['nan'] * itemsCount  # fixed size?

    with open(fileName, "r") as fi, open(fileName+'.out', "w") as fo:
            for line in fi:
                items = line.strip().split(' ')
                if len(items) == 1:
                    items.extend(fill)
                line = ' '.join(items)
                fo.write(line + '\n')

fillNans(r'c:\dmp.txt')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create double line breaks for lines that already contain line break?